# Strange behavior displaying a list from an array in d3.js

Tags: arrays, d3.js

someone knows why I have a completely srewed up layout in my d3 scales while entering or updating array values **between 5 and 9 and bigger than 100** ?

I have setted up here the example: http://bl.ocks.org/vertighel/5149663

[image: barchart]

As you can see from the code and in this picture, the bar chart must not exceed a width of 500px and a color of orange...
but try to insert a value between 5 and 9 or bigger than 100 and you'll see. Let's change the "11" in "9":

[image: screwed up]

width and color scale completely screwed up!

This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf8"></meta>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
  li{border: 1px solid white; background-color: steelblue; color: white}
  li{width: 50px; text-align:right; }
  li:hover{opacity:0.7;}
  .clicked{background-color: green}
  :invalid{background-color: pink}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" value="1,23,42,20,11,33,21" pattern="(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*" required>
<label for="inp">change me</label>
<h1>click on the bars</h1>

<script>

var list = d3.select("body").append("ul");

update()
d3.select("input").on("change",update)

function update(){
var array = d3.select("input").property("value").split(",")
console.log(array);

var cscale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain(d3.extent(array))
.range(["steelblue","orange"])

var wscale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain(d3.extent(array))
.range(["10px","500px"])

var elem = list.selectAll("li").data(array);

elem.enter()
.append("li")

elem.text(function(d){return d})
.transition()
.style("width", function(d){return wscale(d)})
.style("background-color", function(d){return cscale(d)})

elem.on("click",function(d,i){d3.select("h1").text("list item "+i+" has value "+d)})

elem.exit().remove()

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this because your numbers aren't actually numbers, but strings. In particular, a "9" is only one character long while all your other "numbers" are two characters long (similarly for "100").

The solution is to convert your strings into integers. One way of doing this is to use the `map()` function as follows. Replace

```
var array = d3.select("input").property("value").split(",")
```

to

```
var array = d3.select("input").property("value").split(",")
              .map(function(d) { return(+d); });
```

The `map()` function may or may not be implemented in your setup, see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm) for more information and an implementation you can use.